# Default SharePoint permissions on a new site

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to have a newly created SharePoint 2010 Site have default permissions (ie have an Active Directory group already on it).

I am using TFS 2010 and it creates a SharePoint 2010 site for new projects.  But I then have to remember to go into the project and add permissions.  It would be nice if I could have a default AD Group that always goes in the site.  (It would be cooler if I could use TFS Groups that are specific to the project, but I realize that is asking a bit too much.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest thing that comes to mind is to create a feature that adds the permissions you need and associate it with a site template with [feature stapling](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/introduction-to-sharepoint-feature-stapling-part-1).

This will allow you to effectively have the permissions added automatically when you create a new site from that template. If you want more dynamic functionality regarding which security groups get added to your SharePoint groups, you could build this into the feature receiver.

Comment: That sounds like it will work.  However, if I write a custom feature then I have to get it validated (ie tested).  I was hoping there was a way to do this via SharePoint Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the group and members from webservices

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774470%28office.12%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772683%28office.12%29.aspx